Attach Weapon to Character Hand
My "engine" is heavily based on this article.
The overall Question:
How to attach weapon to "character arm"?
Although animations work for all characters and animations at mixamorg website including multiple animations im having the hardest time trying to take a separate model and attach that model to the character's ARM/Hand.
void ArmedAnimatedModel::attachHand(const glm::vec3& playerPosition) {
   std::string boneName = "mixamorig_RightHand";
   std::string parentBoneName = "mixamorig_RightForeArm";

   Bone* bone = GetBoneByName(boneName);
   Bone* parentBone = GetBoneByName(parentBoneName);

   glm::mat4 childfinalBoneMatrix = GetFinalBoneMatrixByID(bone->GetBoneID());
   glm::mat4 parentfinalBoneMatrix = GetFinalBoneMatrixByID(parentBone->GetBoneID());

   // Combine the parent and child bone transformations maybe?
   glm::mat4 finalBoneMatrix = childfinalBoneMatrix; 


   glm::mat4 weaponModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);     

   weaponModelMatrix = glm::scale(weaponModelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.01f));

   weaponModelMatrix = glm::translate(weaponModelMatrix, glm::vec3(X,Y,Z));
   LogMatrix(weaponModelMatrix, "final Weapon Model matrix");
   weaponModel->GetShader()->use();

   LogMatrix(finalBoneMatrix, "finalBoneMatrix");

   auto transforms = finalBoneMatrix;
   weaponModel->GetShader()->setMat4("finalBoneMatrix", transforms);
   GLint uniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(weaponModel->GetShader()->ID,
                                                              "finalBoneMatrix");

   glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE,&transforms[0][0]);
   GLuint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(weaponModel->GetShader()->ID, "model");
   glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(weaponModelMatrix));
   weaponModel->Draw();
}

The shader:
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;       // Vertex position
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;    // Vertex normal
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;   // Texture coordinates

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 finalBoneMatrix;

void main()
{
   vec4 totalPosition = vec4(0.0f);
   Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal; // Correct normal transformat
ion
   TexCoord = aTexCoord;

   vec4 localPosition = finalBoneMatrix * vec4(aPos,1.0f);
   totalPosition += localPosition;
   mat4 viewModel = view * model;
   gl_Position = projection * viewModel * totalPosition; // Final position in clip s
pace
}

I know it looks here that im not passing in the view and projection but i do that somehwere else not trying to muddy up with too much code, below is my vertex shader:
I tried many alternative approaches including multiplying parent by child matrices, but i never get the right location of the arm in WORLD Space or Model Space.
I know the bones are right because its correct relative to each other AND animations work without a hitch...

In all this text there is no actual question, and I think you will find more people that can help you at the Khronos forums.  https://community.khronos.org/

Thank you for reply,
The overall question is How to attach weapon to hand?
what matrixes do i have to multiply and pass onto the shader to do it properly?

what is happening is though the weapon renders it shows up at his feet not at his arm!
Furthermore when i change animations to "walking" the weapon should translate down but it actually goes up in Y direction!

I don't know the answer, I just know that there are more people here who can help you with "C++" than "opengl". And that the khronos forum will probably be visited by people who know more "opengl" than "c++".  ;)

Well ok, I'll post there as well. However I think this IS more of a C++ question as I'm asking how the matrix multiplication of the bones in the animation should translate from bone space to world space.  This is not a question of how to draw/render...

The question is rather language-agnostic, it just happens that you use the libraries written for C++. In principle you just need the 6-DOF transformation between your position (I assume it's some "center", or maybe "bottom" of your "character") and the hand. Then if "attach weapon to hand" means "I want the weapon to have the same position as hand", you don't need to do anything more, 6-DOF position of the hand is 6-DOF position of the weapon. But I have no clue what these GetFinalBoneMatrix* functions return, maybe it's not the transformation you need.

Weapons and similar attachments are essntially extra bones (and a cape or other "flexies" would be an etire limb in old games, though today  it is often solved differently to allow complex physics) and process should be similar, location, position, and scale inherited from "joint" they're attached to. If you was going with rigged model of character, it is meaning that weapon is rigged to hand bone (or somea auxilary bone on hand). You might look up for old blogs or articles about WoW,they actually were quite frank about some stuff.

This is impossible to answer without a full [mre]. The final bone matrix transforms vertices to model space and you still need your MVP matrix to go to screen space. Start with a simple projection * view * model * boneMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0f). If you want to transform the sword relative to the hand, add another matrix transformation between boneMatrix and vec4(pos, 1.0f).

Multiplying "total bone matrices" together is nonsensical, you only do that with the "relative" matrices in a parent-child relationship.

Your normal calculation is also wrong, it needs to take the finalBoneMatrix into account.

Your shader just needs an extra input:
#version 330 core

...

uniform mat4 weapon;          /* weapon -> hand */
uniform mat4 hand;            /* hand -> model */
uniform mat4 model;           /* model -> world */
uniform mat4 view;            /* world -> view */
uniform mat4 projection;      /* view -> clip */

...

void main()
{
  // normal transformation, does not take bone transformation into account so lighting will be screwed up
   Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;
   TexCoord = aTexCoord;

   vec4 modelPosition = hand * weapon * vec4(aPos,1.0f); // Position relative to model
   gl_Position = projection * view * model * modelPosition; // Final position in clip space
}

where hand is the final bone matrix of your hand and weapon is whatever transformations you want to do relative to the hand (eg your weaponModelMatrix)
It is also common to make an extra bone as child of the hand that just serves as a weapon attachment point. This allows you to model the weapon with "Y is up" and have it pointing the correct way.

The normal calculation could be Normal = (model * hand * weapon * vec4(aNormal, 0.0f)).xyz but I have no way of verifying this.

so it turns out there was a way to transform from model space to bone space in my BoneInfoMap object.
struct BoneInfo
{
        /*id is index in finalBoneMatrices*/
        int id;
        std::string parentBoneName;
        /*offset matrix transforms vertex from model space to bone space*/
        glm::mat4 offset;

};

so i decided to use the inverseMatrix of offset to compute my model/world transformation!
Ultimately this boils down to:
void ArmedAnimatedModel::attachHand(const glm::vec3& playerPosition) {
    std::string boneName = "mixamorig_RightHand";
        
    Bone* bone = GetBoneByName(boneName);
        
    glm::mat4 childfinalBoneMatrix = GetFinalBoneMatrixByID(bone->GetBoneID());


    BoneInfo boneInfo = GetBoneInfoByName(boneName);

    // Combine the parent and child bone transformations
    glm::mat4 finalBoneMatrix = childfinalBoneMatrix * inverseMatrix(boneInfo.offset);

    glm::mat4 scaleBoneMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f));
        
    glm::mat4 weaponModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 rotationX = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(rotX), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 rotationY = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(rotY), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 rotationZ = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(rotZ), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = rotationZ * rotationY * rotationX;

    weaponModelMatrix = weaponModelMatrix * rotationMatrix;

    weaponModelMatrix = glm::scale(weaponModelMatrix, glm::vec3(0.01f));

    weaponModelMatrix = finalBoneMatrix * weaponModelMatrix;
    LogMatrix(weaponModelMatrix, "final Weapon Model matrix");
    weaponModelMatrix = glm::translate(weaponModelMatrix, playerPosition + glm::vec3(X,Y,Z));
    weaponModel->GetShader()->use();
    LogMatrix(finalBoneMatrix, "finalBoneMatrix");
    GLuint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(weaponModel->GetShader()->ID, "model");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(weaponModelMatrix));
    weaponModel->Draw();
}

This leads to the weapon being placed right on the arm! of course the local weapon rotation needs some adjustment but everything is correct across different animation poses!
and as for the shader it is simply:
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;       // Vertex position
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;    // Vertex normal
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;   // Texture coordinates

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;

    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);

}


Really Appreciate the comments and the help! Thank you all!!! :)

By the way, all models are loaded with ASSIMP.

Doesn't childfinalBoneMatrix * inverseMatrix(boneInfo.offset) just calculate the final boneMatrix of the arm bone? It seems like you are recalculating the player position too? Why not reuse the player's model matrix at least?

As far as i understand it:
The childfinalBoneMatrix IS bone space and to get to model space we  need to multiply it by the inverse of boneInfo.offset matrix to get it right.  As for player position its coming from physics and your right that that translation isn't entirely accurate. I just updated and found a solution to it including player orientation.... i have a simulation where balls hit my player "capsule" model or just the character for simplicity he rotates and falls across a hieghtmap generated floor and then falls off the world so i know its right.

I could share that code if your really interested...

I'm also using 2 different shaders one for the character and one for the weapon that's why i dont reuse the character model matrix btw....as they are 2 separate models this gives me flexibility to attach to any body part any weapon etc....
